# Slim framework shared code in routes

Tags: php, slim

I have a route group with 6 routes inside it. I check the parameters on every route against the database.

What's the best way to achieve this? Build a class for it?

Answer (score 0):

When working with a database, it really depends on how much you will be using it. Slim has no database integration, so you could access the database by either using basic php or using a ORM tool to assist you in talking with your database.

One orm that is quick and easy to use is idiorm http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

There are other more robust things out there and it all depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Really, to give a "best" solution, we would need more information on the situation and also how you would quantify "best."

Answer (score 0):

Try use Slim [Middleware](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Middleware-Overview).

Add your check part as one middleware, and share a middleware for all routes. Then you will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can also try using class instances as route callbacks.

Define a base class with all the database functionality and use "Class Controllers" available since version [2.4.0](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/releases/tag/2.4.0) (November 2013).

```
class Base  {
    // Define all your shared DB methods and properties here
}
```

Use child classes of your base class as controller class instances, as callbacks for your Slim app routes (and their parameters):

```
$app->get('/user/:id/', '\Base\User:find');
```

Getting an instance of $app in the callback class instance is easy enough:

```
class User extends \Base {
    public function find($theUserId) {
        // ...
        // You can easily get access to $app here, too:
        // $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    }
}
```